# Invariant Violation error while upgrading styled-componentsv4

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, styled-components, next.js

While upgrading the existing styled-components to v4 on Next-react-redux application, we are getting this error:

> Invariant Violation: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"attrs":[],"componentStyle":{"rules":[".app &{",null,";",null,";}"],"isStatic":false,"componentId":"withStyles-l4k83c-0"}

In my `package.json`:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "next": "^5.1.0",
    "next-redux-saga": "^1.0.1",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^1.3.5",
    "next-routes": "^1.2.0",
"react": "^16.3.0",
"react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
"styled-components":  "^4.1.3",
```

What am I missing during the upgrade??

Answer (score 0):

styled-components started to use React.forwardRef from version 4 and older versions of react-redux did have wrong check for react components. so react-redux should be updated to at least 5.1.0 - thread -> https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/914